# Convert Reflection.Emit to Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, reflection.emit

I need to convert an existing code that uses Reflection.Emit to Roslyn.

The code I have currently is basically this:

```
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("AssemblyName");
var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);

var builder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("test", "test.dll");

var type = builder.DefineType("Entry", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(object), null);

var method = type.DefineMethod("###Start_v1.4.3.0", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig);
method.SetReturnType(typeof(void));

var generator = method.GetILGenerator();

generator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

type.CreateType();

assemblyBuilder.Save(@"test.dll");
```

As you can see, there is a class named `Entry` with a method called `###Start_v1.4.3.0`.

We're using this for more than 7 years now but evereytime we need to change anything, it's a pain because we need to use those `Emits` and it's not trivial.

It would be great if we could just have Roslyn to compile the code:

```
public class Entry
{
    public void ###Start_v1.4.3.0()
    {
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work due to the method name being invalid.

The compiled dll is used by a third party component and it looks for this class and method name to execute. We tried to reach the developers to have a new version but no luck.

I think Roslyn won't compile this at all, but I believe there might be a way to rename the method name later from let's say just `Start()` to `###Start_v1.4.3.0()`... I just don't know how to do this.

Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: I suppose you could use [Ildasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) and [Ilasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx), or Cecil, to patch afterwards.

Comment: Maybe you should pose the feature request to have a mode where arbitrary member names are allowed. The CLR has not problems with these names and I don't think anything in Roslyn would break from just allowing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only problem is the illegal method name, you can easily resolve that issue.

Compile the dll with a legal name, and then you have several ways to change the method name.

With `mono.cecil` its pretty simple.

```
public void ChangeMethodName()
{
    //Before changing the method name
    var assem = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\temp\ClassLibrary1.dll");
    Console.WriteLine(
        assem.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1").
        GetMethod("Start", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).
        Invoke(null, null));

    // Change the name
    var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(@"C:\temp\ClassLibrary1.dll");
    TypeDefinition myType = 
        module.Types.First(type => type.Name == "Class1");
    var method = myType.Methods.First(m => m.Name == "Start");
    method.Name = "###Start_v1.4.3.0";
    module.Write(@"C:\temp\ClassLibrary1_new.dll");

    //After changing the method name
    assem = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\temp\ClassLibrary1_new.dll");
    Console.WriteLine(
        assem.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1").
        GetMethod("###Start_v1.4.3.0",
                  BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public).
        Invoke(null, null));
}



public class Class1
{
    public static string Start()
    {
        return $"my name is {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}";
    }
}
```